# Blender 2.79: Issue with Texture Painting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-painting

The previous model I did had no issues with texture paint, it worked normally, but this time. . .not so much. I've looked through other solutions on here and various websites but I can't seem to fix it.

I've already:

1. Unwrapped and created an UV Map
2. Set up my nodes (crtl + T and Shift + crtl + click for textures) and
   hooked up my UV map to the Image Texture node. Made sure everything
   to the left of that node was set up appropriately. Followed a tutorial to 
   make sure this was right
3. Made sure the texture in Tools tab in Texture Paint is off.
4. Checked slots tab and made sure everything was set up fine.

I can still paint directly on UV Map and when I try to fill the 3D model itself, nothing happens. The oddest thing that just cropped up is that when I paint the UV Map, the preview area becomes completely white. Never had that happen before.

[image]
[Blender file here.](https://sta.sh/02bt84x975y6)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to fix this for the past day with no luck. I'm also working with the top half, the human half, only.

Comment: It worked fine for me. I saw two problems, You have 2 materials applied one with nothing connected to the material output and another that you have only the viewer node on. I would just erase both materials and start over. Go to uv editor create new Image to paint on to, then make sure Image Texture node is highlighted before going into texture paint mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 materials applied one with nothing connected to the material output and another that you have only the viewer node on"? Also, I have reset and started over twice today and several other times yesterday with no success. As for the last bit, didn't help either. ^.^"

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem area (due to some help on another forum), which was a slight overlook:
[image]